# Is there a way to test sql queries in exacttarget?

Tags: unit-test, marketing-cloud, query, console

I'm wondering if there is any sort of developer console where you can test sql queries.
Testing queries by always looking into the regarding data extension takes quite a lot of time.

Anyone having experiences or workaround for this kind of issue?

Comment: ohh I miss this feature so much! It a pain to make Queries in ExactTarget. I should be like in Responsys, where it makes the output Data Extension for you, and you can check midways the count of the query.

Comment: @ma_wi  https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FP3yFUAT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend writing and testing your Query Activities outside of the platform using a local installation **[Microsoft SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx)** or **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)** (using MS SQL Server 2008).  It doesn't make sense for all queries, but with a query that has some complexity to it, I build and test it locally.

As you may have noticed, if you query has any kind of *runtime* error, you'll have to contact SFMC Support to determine the source of the error.

Also, if you're dealing with the System Data Views, expect and plan for your queries to exceed the 30 minute timeout threshold.  Give each data view it's own query if you need that data in your final result-set.

Reference:

[Query Activity (System Data Views)](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Adam. I hoped there was some tool like the developer workbench for Sales Cloud where you can test queries on live production data, but in this case I'll work with the given tools.

Comment: Yeah I wish there was as well. Waiting for 30 minutes to see if the query worked and is slow or failed makes development time days instead of hours

Comment: I've heard from some of the Product Development folks that they're planning to show SQL runtime errors in the interface.  That'll be nice.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs any news about a tool to show SQL runtime execution?

Comment: @ÁtilaCastroAlves https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FP3yFUAT